# вывод данных из firebase vue

Tags: vue.js, firebase

Всем привет. Не могу понять почему пропадают данные после обновления страницы.
Есть вот такой компонент vue

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Add task"
            v-model="name"
          >
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="addLocation">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Tasks</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(location, idx) in locations" :key="idx">
          <th scope="row">{{ location.name }} <button class="btn btn-danger" >X</button></th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { db } from '../main'

    export default {
        data () {
            console.log(this.locations);
            return {
                locations: [],
                name: ''
            }
        },
        created () {
            this.getTasks();
        },
        methods: {
             getTasks(){
                 db.collection('locations').get().then(querySnapshot => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        const data = {
                            'id': doc.id,
                            'name': doc.data().name
                        };
                        this.locations.push(data);
                    });
                })
            },
            addLocation () {
                db.collection('locations').add({
                    name: this.name
                }).then(this.getTasks)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

В первый раз данные из firebase нормально выводятся, но после обновления страницы они пропадают. Новичок в vue, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.

Comment: А вы данные сохраняете где-то ?)

Comment: сохраняю в firestore